# Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно затранскрибировала ли?

Tags: транскрипция

развалина -[р^звАл'инъ],  скоро-[скОръ], бежать-[б'[иэ]жАт'], ручей-[ручЭj], сиявший-[с'ыjафш[ыэ]j] (здесь сомневаюсь, может быть [ы]?), сиявший-[с'ыjАфш[ыэ]j], темной-[т'Омнъj], листва-[л'иствА], дорога-[дърОгъ], трещина-[трЭш[долгая]ина], живописец-[жывап'Ис'ьц], погода-[пОгодъ], городской-[гаратскОj], деловой-[д'ьлавОj]

Answer (score 1):

сиявший-[с'иjАфшый],
ручей-[ручЭй],
дорога-[д^рОгъ],
трещина-[тр'Эш(долг.)инъ],
 живописец-[жыв^п'Ис'ьц] ,
погода-[п^гОдъ], 
деловой-[д'и(э)л^вОй].

Comment: Людмила, спасибо! У меня возникли вопросы: 1. Почему использовали й? Она используется в школе, я учусь в институте и нас учат писать вместо й- йот. 2. насчет д[иэ]л^вой почему [иэ]? Мы на лекции писали, что [иэ] произноситься в первом предудар.слоге после тверд.согл.

Comment: й обозначается какj в йотированных (я=jа), на конце слова звучит не сверхкраткий, а полугласный,он поётся, тянется,я обозначила его й, на самом деле нужно было хвостик-запятую не вверху, а внизу, но здесь такой возможности нет. И с призвуком э произносится вместо Е-Э после мягких, а после твёрдых - нет звука.Посмотрите здесь;
http://nashol.com/2012011562874/foneticheskaya-transkripciya.html
http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part1.htm

Comment: Возможно, у вас в вузе  й в конце слова обозначается как i c крючочком внизу, но не как j .

Comment: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-025.htm#i1931

Comment: http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=663125ae-c4bc-459f-adcd-cb0edbdbf2d1